# circular reference in class diagram

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram, circular-reference

I have five database tables:

- documentTemplate
- area
- Zone
- KeyWord
- DocumentField

> a document template is composed of areas
>   an area is composed of zones 
>   a documentTemplate is composed of keyWords

*zones and keyWords belong to a Field ( documentField )* 
this is my class diagram : 
[image]
how do i  split the circular reference between these tables ? 
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: it seems you are facing many times the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719371/how-do-i-avoid-a-circular-relationship-in-my-class-diagram/23719422?noredirect=1#comment36455739_23719422 :)

Comment: yes but in different modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to make both associations of DocumentField unidirectional (either towards DocumentField or vice versa).

Bidirectional associations are a common source of circular dependencies in a model and should be rarely used - basically between very close elements in the same scope. Then they cannot cause this kind of problems.

If this solution is not good for you, I suggest to try to break this 5 classes in 2 or 3 packages and then concentrate on removing circular dependencies between the packages and not single classes.